# Inno Setup, run code step by step

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create a file and then merge it with another one. Both steps work individually, but not together.

Code:

```
[Code]
function CreateAcad: Boolean;
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName:= ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2009\Support\acad.lsp');
  SetArrayLength(Lines, 3);
  Lines[0] := 'echo hello';
  Lines[1] := 'pause';
  Lines[2] := 'exit';
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(FileName, Lines, True);
end;

procedure AppendFile(const SrcFile, DestFile: string);
var
  SrcStream: TFileStream;
  DestStream: TFileStream;
begin
  SrcStream := TFileStream.Create(SrcFile, fmOpenRead);
  try
    DestStream := TFileStream.Create(DestFile, fmOpenWrite);
    try
      DestStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
      DestStream.CopyFrom(SrcStream, SrcStream.Size);
    finally
      DestStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SrcStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
    CreateAcad;
  AppendFile('C:\COBIAX\Cordoli\acad.lsp', 'C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2009\Support\acad.lsp');
end;
```

Comment: Please precise your question. What do you want to do? What is your problem? And btw. it's easier to read when you post your code snippets into the question body.

Comment: You must enclose those two lines into a `begin end;` block. Without it, the `AppendFile` one will be called with every step change.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep it in mind.

Well I want to create an empty file called Acad.lsp and put it in a specific folder. After doing that i want to merge that file with another one who contains the visualisp code i need to run with autocad.
The problem is that if i put both istructions together it doesn't create the file and the "appendfile" procedure returns me the error "file not found"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xfbwJXTH solution here :)

Ok, how can i menage if the file already exist? I don't want to add that code infinite times.

Thanks TLama :)

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. We are making from Stack Overflow a discussion forum. That's not what it is ;-) ([`FileExists`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) can tell you that, but for the next time ask one question per *thread*, please)

Comment: Ok, sorry, you'll find a lot of my question then XD